# Lindelöf in terms of filters

Tags: general-topology, filters

The following characterisation of compactness is well known.

> Let $X$ be a space. Then $X$ is compact if and only if every filter on $X$ has a cluster point if and only if every ultrafilter on $X$ converges.

Now recall that a space is *Lindelöf* if every open covering of it has a countable subcovering.

My question is whether there is a characterisation of the Lindelöf property in terms of filters similar to the statement given above for compactness.

Comment: Engelking and the Encyclopedia of General Topology don't mention any, so probably not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A space $X$ is Lindelöf iff every filter on $X$ with the countable intersection property has a cluster point. (A filter $\mathscr{F}$ has the countable intersection property if $\bigcap\mathscr{C}\ne\varnothing$ whenever $\mathscr{C}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ is countable.) I doubt that you can get an analogue for the ultrafilter part, though. An ultrafilter with the countable intersection property would be countably complete. Take $X$ to be $\omega_1$ with the discrete topology. The only countably complete ultrafilter on $\omega_1$ are the principal ultrafilters, which all converge, but $X$ is not Lindelöf.

**Added:** I should probably add that this is not a special property of $\omega_1$. There is a countably complete free (i.e., non-principal) ultrafilter on a set $X$ iff $|X|$ is a [measurable cardinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal), and the existence of any such cardinals cannot be proved in $\mathsf{ZFC}$. They are well up in the [hierarchy of large cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_large_cardinal_properties).

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that ZFC cannot prove the existence of a *free* ultrafilter which is countably complete. And the existence of such ultrafilter is equivalent to the existence of a measurable cardinal, which is not a small large cardinal.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: It was a conscious decision on my part to avoid measurable cardinals altogether, but you may have persuaded me to change my mind.

Comment: It was a conscious decision on my part. :)

Comment: I think you'd get more into realcompactness when trying ultrafilter analogues of this. Classic fact: an ultrafilter of functionally closed sets with the c.i.p. converges ifff $X$ is realcompact (in the realm of Tychonoff spaces); I don't know what happens if we drop the functionally closed though.